# AngularJS conditional display if there are no attribute values

Tags: angularjs, conditional-statements

I'm fairly new to AngularJS and I'm wanting to create a conditional display for if a file in my system has no attributes it will display "This file has no attributes"

My html is currently this:

```
<div>
    <br />                 
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li ng-repeat="fileInfo in fileResources">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <span class="label label-default">{{fileInfo.DocType}}</span>
                    <span class="panel-title">{{fileInfo.Name}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="panel panel-info" ng-if="fileInfo.fileAttributes">
                        <div class="panel-heading">file Attributes</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                        <ac-file-attributes
                            file-attributes="fileInfo.fileAttributes"
                            display-options="displayOptions">
                        </ac-file-attributes>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel panel-info" ng-if="fileInfo.PhysicalProperties" >
                        <div class="panel-heading">Physical Properties</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <ac-physical-properties
                                phys-props="fileInfo.PhysicalProperties" 
                                display-options="displayOptions">
                            </ac-physical-properties>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `ng-if` (add/remove DOM elements) or `ng-show` (hide/show elements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the above code already works, presumable you could use the following, which simply 'nots' the fileInfo.fileAttributes

```
<div class="panel panel-info" ng-if="!fileInfo.fileAttributes">
                    <div class="panel-heading">file Attributes</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                    <ac-file-attributes
                        file-attributes="fileInfo.fileAttributes"
                        display-options="displayOptions">
                    </ac-file-attributes>
                    </div>
```